# Directive not showing what I want on the HTML?

Tags: html, angularjs, svg, angular-directive, angular-template

So I have a custom directive in AngularJS used to draw a circle via SVG. For some reason when the page loads, it doesn't draw the circle, nor does my text show up that's within the template.

Why is that?

Here's a plunker of what I have. [plnkr.co/edit/1hHB2yXlhb3trMWPpXUC?](http://plnkr.co/edit/1hHB2yXlhb3trMWPpXUC?)

Here's the code of the directive and it's HTML.

```
   <div>
    <b>Data Sources:</b>
    <b>  Auto-Tagged Events - </b>
<svg width="50" height="50">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>

    <b>  GLIDR - </b>
    <svg width="50" height="50">
        <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5" fill="blue"></circle>
    </svg>

    <b> J9/CIDNE</b>
    <svg width="50" height="50">
        <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5" fill="yellow"></circle>
    </svg>
</div>



   (function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('legend', legend);

    /* @ngInject */

    function legend(){
        var ddo = {
            restrict: 'EA',
            templateURL: 'draw-circle.directive.html',
            link: link

        };

        return ddo;

        function link(scope, element, attrs){

        }

    }
    })();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made several mistakes while creating an app

1. You should add `ng-app="app"` inside your page html tag
2. Replace angularjs refernce from [**`this`**](https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular.js) to [**`this`**](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js)
3. `templateURL` should be `templateUrl` inside directive.
4. `templateUrl` should be `legend.directive.html` like `templateUrl: 'legend.directive.html',`
5. Add you directive inside `body` tag.

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZwQqVuTPotKgGLavx4Cy?p=preview)